# How to assign javascript function to an element attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to assign a javascript function to an HTML attribute. for eg:

```
 <li data-ng-repeat="job in jobList" class= foo(str) data-filter = "foo1(str)">
```

i want to do this because the class name and data attribute changes by job. 
finding the `<li>` element  and changing is not possible as it is a list of elements.

i tried using

```
class=foo(str)
class = javascipt'foo(Str);'
```

not able to get it right.

Comment: Are there supposed to be quotes surrounding `foo(str)` after `class=`? Edit: You must include quotes around `foo(str)` otherwise it is NOT valid HTML.

Comment: Does `data-ng-class` not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<li data-ng-repeat="job in jobList" class="{{foo(str)}}" data-filter = "foo1(str)">
```

However that will only work if `foo` is on the global namespace. Assuming you have put `foo` on the `scope` then the code is the following:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="job in jobList" class="{{scope.foo(str)}}" data-filter = "foo1(str)">
```

AngularJS will evaluate `foo` every time the DOM is drawn

Comment: Keep in mind I am assuming you are familiar with and running AngularJS since you are using the `data-ng-repeat` tag. My solution requires AngularJS to be setup properly with a controller.

Comment: Damn.. how stupid of me.. i completely forgot that i can use angular.. somehow i was thinking of only typical onclick kind of solution. Thanks @samuel

Comment: Haha no problem Karty! :) Could you please go accept my answer so I can get that delicious `reputation`!